# Linq InnerJoin 4 tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My goal is to return a list of orders that only contain orderItems that are from a specific merchant. My current solution is to iterate through EVERY order, then through every order item and every listing. I imagine that is not the best practice, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to construct a single query to retrieve merchant specific orders.

I have 4 tables

Merchants(the id field being merchantID)

Orders(the id field is orderID)

orderItems(the id field is orderItemID, and FK listingID)

listings(the id field is listingID, and FK merchantID)

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: You don't want a cross join.  You want an inner join.

Comment: @jvanrhyn - Yes, using EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.Any()` to help you get to where you want:

```
var ordersFromMerchant = db.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Items.Any(oi => oi.Listing.merchantID = 10);
```

I've made assumptions about the names of your navigation properties, but you should be able to adapt this if they don't match.

If you prefer the linq syntax, you can use:

```
var ordersFromMerchant = from o in db.Orders
    join oi in db.orderItems on o.orderID equals oi.orderID
    join l in db.listings on oi.listingID equals l.listingID
    where l.merchantID = 10
    select o;
```

Comment: `equals` not `=` in the query syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I normally use the extension method syntax!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your structure but something like this should work.

```
var query = from o in orders
            join oi in orderItems on o.id equals io.orderID
            join l in listings on oi.listingID equals l.id
            where l.merchantID == merchantID
            select o;
```